# Nagios 404 Warning with check_http

Tags: nagios

A couple of days ago all of our check_http commands began throwing warnings with the following message:

```
Site Access - Images;WARNING;SOFT;1;HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found - 492 bytes in 0.008 second response time
```

Neither the OS nor Nagios were updated or modified anywhere near to the time the warnings began.

This is one of the entries in the cfg file:

```
define service {
  use                  my-service
  host_name            web01
  service_description  Site Access - MyApp
  check_command        check_http!myapp.mydomain.com!-S --onredirect=follow
  contact_groups       alert-admins
}
```

check_http from the command line works fine:

```
./check_http -H myapp.mydomain.com -u /space.gif -f follow -v

    GET /space.gif HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: check_http/v1.4.15 (nagios-plugins 1.4.15)
    Connection: close
    Host: myapp.mydomain.com

    http://myapp.mydomain.com:80/space.gif is 307 characters
    STATUS: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the command line version was working, I replaced all of the failing check_http commands with with the following (or similar):

```
define command {
  command_name check_http-web01-myapp
  command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H myapp.mydomain.com -f follow -S
}

define service {
  use                  my-service
  host_name            web01
  service_description  Site Access - MyApp
  check_command        check_http-web01-myapp
  contact_groups       alert-admins
}
```

And the checks started working again.

I realize I should look into the check_http command definition within Nagios and see what it's doing, but the replacement is working....